# How to use markdown for python with PyCharm?

Tags: python, markdown, pycharm

I'm new to python and I've been using PyCharm (4.5 Community Edition) as my IDE on a Mac OS X v11 system.  I've installed the [markdown plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5970?pr=idea_ce) and enabled the package in pycharm (Actions>Plugins>Markdown is checked, program restart complete).

When I create a new markdown file (test.md or test.markdown) I can see the preview tab.  But I don't see anything in the preview tab. Also, I can't "run / execute" this file.  So seeing a preview would be nice.  Ideally, I would like to be able to execute python chunks with markdown comments in-between and see the output rendered in a local browser if this at all is possible.

This was really easy in the Rstudio IDE and a super powerful way to communicate findings.

Any suggestions?  Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that a much better way to achieve what I was trying to accomplish when I asked this question is to utilize jupyter notebook ([jupyter.org/](http://jupyter.org/)).

Answer (score 7):

The default setting for Markdown files - with a fresh copy of `Pycharm` - is `preview mode` only:

[image: preview_only_mode]

Just change it to `side-by-side mode`:

[image: sidebyside_mode]

No requirement to install additional plug-ins.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/markdown.html#preview

Answer (score 6):

1. Uninstall Markdown Support (by Jetbrains) (has **no** side preview)
2. Install Markdown Navigator 2.0 (by Vladimir Schneider) (has side-preview)

https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown

This should give you a per-compiled side view of you `.md` file.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

Currently PyCharm has two plugin options for `.md` format: PlantUML and Mermaid.

According to the official [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/markdown.html#code-blocks), in order to enable `md` support:

- Go to File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Markdown.

  (in recent versions: Pycharm -> Preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> Markdown)
- Install either of these plugins.
- Close and Reopen PyCharm (it did not work instantly for me)
- In order to see a file preview move a mouse to the upper right corner and select this option.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm on the same boat. Making transition from RStudio to PyCharm. You can install markdown plugins directly within the PyCharm settings. Within Pycharm I searched and downloaded "Markdown support". Once you're editing the Markdown file, you should have a "view" to see the markdown in raw or rendered format and even some formatting buttons like in a normal Text Editor.

I think you need to follow these tag [instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-documentation-comments.html#create_tag) to have the HTML render correctly.

You should also take a look at [IntelliLang](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/using-language-injections.html)  for language injections, which I think are equivalent to R "chunks".